# How to transpose a list column and add the resulting list as columns?

Tags: r, list, purrr

I used a "safe" function (created with `purrr::safely`) to do some webscraping, adding the results to a data frame as a `list` column. The safe function outputs have, of course, two elements each, "result" and "error", and I'd like to convert these to data frame columns and unnest results. I can do this one at a time, but I would like a scalable solution (in case there are more columns).

Here's a simple example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

foo = function(x) {
  if(x == 1) stop("x cannot be 1")
  data.frame(v1 = 1:2, v2 = c("a", "b"))
}

foo_safe = purrr::safely(foo)

input = data.frame(x = 0:2)

(input = input %>% 
  mutate(foo_output = map(x, foo_safe)))
#   x             foo_output
# 1 0             1, 2, a, b
# 2 1 x cannot be 1, .f(...)
# 3 2             1, 2, a, b
```

```
## desired output
input %>%
  mutate(
    result = map(foo_output, pluck, "result"),
    error = map(foo_output, pluck, "error")
  ) %>%
  unnest(result, keep_empty = TRUE)
# # A tibble: 5 x 5
#       x foo_output          v1 v2    error     
#   <int> <list>           <int> <chr> <list>    
# 1     0 <named list [2]>     1 a     <NULL>    
# 2     0 <named list [2]>     2 b     <NULL>    
# 3     1 <named list [2]>    NA NA    <smplErrr>
# 4     2 <named list [2]>     1 a     <NULL>    
# 5     2 <named list [2]>     2 b     <NULL>
```

Answer (score 1):

`purrr::transpose` flips the list to the right hierarchy, but there's still a challenge to get the tranposed list added as columns. `as.data.frame()` will fail, but `as_tibble()` is happy to create a data frame with list columns that we can bind to the original data:

```
input %>%
  bind_cols(
    as_tibble(transpose(.$foo_output))
  ) %>%
  unnest(result, keep_empty = TRUE)

# # A tibble: 5 x 5
#       x foo_output          v1 v2    error     
#   <int> <list>           <int> <chr> <list>    
# 1     0 <named list [2]>     1 a     <NULL>    
# 2     0 <named list [2]>     2 b     <NULL>    
# 3     1 <named list [2]>    NA NA    <smplErrr>
# 4     2 <named list [2]>     1 a     <NULL>    
# 5     2 <named list [2]>     2 b     <NULL>
```